# How would I use bootstrap in this scenario?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a new user of html. I've completed more than half of my website for an assignment for school, and my friend recommended me to use bootstrap. How would we implement bootstrap to all my already-applied css codes? The issue I was having before bootstrap was that my icons and images were being cut off the screen whenever the user zoomed in. This is what it was supposed to look like // before I added bootstrap:
[image]

code:

```
                <div class="ticketsbottom">
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/helios2.jpg)">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/helios.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insidehelios.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2>HELIOS</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$3355</b><br>- Intel Core i7 10700K 3.8GHz<br>- 16GB Gigabyte Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- WD 500GB SSD OS Drive<br>- ASUS RTX 3070 8GB Graphics<br>- eVGA 750W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/coal2.png)">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/hot1.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insidecoal.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2>COAL</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$3360</b><br>- Intel Core i7 10700KF 3.8Ghz<br>- 16GB Gigabyte Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- Samsung 500GB SSD OS Drive<br>- Gigabyte RTX 3070 8GB Graphics<br>- Gigabyte 750W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/remix2.png">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/remix.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insideremix.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <h2>REMIX</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$6270</b><br>- Intel Core i9 10850K 3.6Ghz<br>- 32GB Corsair Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- Samsung 2TB SSD OS Drive<br>- Gigabyte RTX 3090 24GB Graphics<br>- eVGA 1000W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                </div>
```

When I implement the bootstrap:

```
                <div class="ticketsbottom">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-4">
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/helios2.jpg)">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/helios.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insidehelios.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2>HELIOS</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$3355</b><br>- Intel Core i7 10700K 3.8GHz<br>- 16GB Gigabyte Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- WD 500GB SSD OS Drive<br>- ASUS RTX 3070 8GB Graphics<br>- eVGA 750W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-4">
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/coal2.png)">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/hot1.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insidecoal.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2>COAL</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$3360</b><br>- Intel Core i7 10700KF 3.8Ghz<br>- 16GB Gigabyte Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- Samsung 500GB SSD OS Drive<br>- Gigabyte RTX 3070 8GB Graphics<br>- Gigabyte 750W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-4">
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/remix2.png">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/remix.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insideremix.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <h2>REMIX</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$6270</b><br>- Intel Core i9 10850K 3.6Ghz<br>- 32GB Corsair Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- Samsung 2TB SSD OS Drive<br>- Gigabyte RTX 3090 24GB Graphics<br>- eVGA 1000W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

And this is what it looks like when I apply the bootstrap:
[image]

This is the CSS code for this specific area:

```
#tickets {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#ticketstop .sectiontitle h1{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100;

}
.sectiontitle span{
  color: #347f7d;
}

#tickets .sectiontitle{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100;

}

#tickets .sectiontitle span{
  color: #347f7d;
}

#tickets p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: translate(0,-30%);
}

#tickets .ticketsitem {

  flex-basis: 15%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  background-size: cover;
  margin: 10px 6px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: +1;
  transition: .2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;


}

#tickets .ticketsitem::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #26323c 0%, #485563 100%);
  opacity: .8;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon{
  height: 80px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}



#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%,-70%);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 100;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon:hover img{
  opacity: 0
}


#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon .iconinside img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%,-70%);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon .iconinside img:hover{

  opacity: 100;


}


#tickets .ticketsitem h2{
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#tickets .ticketsitem p{
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}



#tickets .ticketsitem:hover{
  position: relative;

  transition: 0.1s;
}

/* END TICKETS Section */
```

This is what it looks like when I zoom in without bootstrap:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a browser window is zoomed in, the size of your content increases, but the width of the veiwport (browser's display area) remains the same. So at 100% the browser behaves like that of a desktop, but at 150% it behaves like tablet browser: more content less space. Without Bootstrap, your content size was increasing and if not handled properly, cause it to "bleed" out if the viewport area and introduce horizontal scrollbars. (which is a bad user experience).

Bootstrap, being a responsive CSS library, is trying to keep the content on the screen, without introducing the horizontal scrollbar, and it's pushing the last item down. You can make this look better by replacing the grid classes: `tickets_item col-sm-12 col-4` by simply `tickets_item col-sm` and it will fit the items in a better way when zoomed in.